# c# Insert data into MySQL database using parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

This probably a simple solution, but I've got a deadline to catch and I don't know the exact problem here. 
So here's the deal, I'm trying to update my table using this piece of code:

```
    private void btn_opslaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string opleidingsid = "Select OpleidingsID From opleidingen Where Opleidingsnaam = '" + cb_opleiding.Text + "'";
        MySqlCommand cmdid = new MySqlCommand(opleidingsid, dbconnect.connection);
        dbconnect.OpenConnection();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmdid.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
            int oplid = (int)reader.GetValue(0);

        cmdid.Dispose();
        reader.Close();
        sql = "UPDATE leerlingen SET Naam = '_naam', Adres = '_adres', Woonplaats = '_woonplaats', Postcode = '_postcode', Email = '_email', Telefoonnummer = '_telefoonnummer', Klas = '_klas', Ovnummer = '_ovnummer', OpleidingsID = '_opleidingsid', Startdatum = '_startdatum', Einddatum = '_einddatum' WHERE LeerlingID = '_leerlingid'";

      //  sql = "UPDATE leerlingen set Naam  = '" + txt_naam.Text + "', Adres = '" + txt_adres.Text + "', Woonplaats = '" + txt_woonplaats.Text + "', Postcode = '" + txt_postcode.Text + "', Email = '" + txt_email.Text + "', Telefoonnummer = '" + txt_telefoonnumer.Text + "', Klas = '" + txt_klas.Text + "', Ovnummer = '" + txt_ovnummer.Text + "', OpleidingsID = '" + oplID + "', Startdatum = '"+mc_startdatum.SelectionStart.Date.ToString()+"', Einddatum = '"+ mc_einddatum.SelectionStart.Date.ToString() +"' WHERE LeerlingID = '" + Int32.Parse(lbl_leerlingid.Text) + "'";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dbconnect.connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_naam", txt_naam.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_adres", txt_adres.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_woonplaats", txt_woonplaats.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_postcode", txt_postcode.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_email", txt_email.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_telefoonnummer", txt_telefoonnumer.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_klas", txt_klas.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_ovnummer", txt_ovnummer.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_opleidingsid", oplid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_startdatum", mc_startdatum.SelectionStart.Date.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_einddatum", mc_einddatum.SelectionStart.Date.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_leerlingid", int.Parse(lbl_leerlingid.Text));

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("opslaan gelukt");
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        dbconnect.CloseConnection();

        this.Close();

    }
```

I've already tried without the single quotes, it would give me the error that colomn '_leerlingid' does not exist, but that is the parameter...
Now, I dont get any errors, but it wouldn't update my database.
Any help please

P.S. Ignore the sql injection please, before this , i didn't knew better before I found out about parameters.

Comment: Just curious - If you are using this commented out query, which is vulnerable to SQL injection, are you getting the behavior that you need?

Comment: @dotnetcom Yes, but for my assignment i'll have to use parameters

Comment: In your `WHERE` condition you have quotes around parameter: `WHERE LeerlingID = '_leerlingid'`. This seems to be the only integer parameter, so quotes are not needed. Try to remove these quotes. I'm just guessing here, because I cannot understand what is not working

Comment: Well, I've already removed all single quotes everywhere and replaced the underscores with @, but my database simply wont update at this point

Comment: I've never used it myself but you can try to enable profiler using [SHOW PROFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) and see what query is actually executed. Seeing raw query might help you to spot the issues, be it in syntax or somewhere else. This is a proven way to troubleshoot issues in SQL Server, so it might help with MySQL as well

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your parameters with the @ symbol and remove the single quotes, like this:

```
SQL = "UPDATE leerlingen SET Naam = @naam, Adres = @adres";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", txt_naam.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adres", txt_adres.Text);
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for your answer, I did this, but i wont update my database with the correct information.

Comment: @JoeyDeLaat Strange, I don't see why it would fail, I've done it before. Do you get an error?

Comment: No, thats what's bothering me too, I could try to create an insert command using parameters and see if that works this way, then its sure its a code problem.

Comment: Have you tried changing the way you do the command? I usually do `MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand(); cmd.Connection = dbconnect.connection; cmd.CommandText = sqlString;` @JoeyDeLaat

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did wrong is you mustn't initialize your MySqlCommand like that. It must be like this..

```
MySqlCommand cmd;

cmd = dbconnect.createCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tableName SET firstname=@firstname, lastname=@lastname where id=@id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", fName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lName.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: dbconnect is a class which doesn't contain a createCommand method so I'm won't be able to call that function

Comment: I thought that dbconnect is your MySqlConnection. Maybe you can change it to whatever your MySqlConnection is.

Comment: I think that what you mean is exactly what i;m doing with MysqlCommand cmd = new MysqlCommand(sql,dbconnect.connection();

Comment: ahm. maybe, but I think it is an other way to initialize MySqlCommand. Did you already try this? I got this format from my Prof in c#.

Answer (score -1):

when I creating a new data in c#, I make it like this ..

//values

```
String a = "COL1ROW1", b = "COL1ROW2";
```

//this is the code for mysql

```
String query = "Insert Into tableName(Column1, Column2)values('" + a + "','" + b + "')";
```

//conn is your mysqlconnection

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

//then execute it

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: In this case stop creating the data this way, because such queries are vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. Using code in such a way is a straight way to a disaster

Comment: True, thats why i commented this method out of my code.

Comment: ahm. what disaster will it make? I always using code like this but i didn't get any errors or anything.

Comment: SQL injection is a technique where malicious users can inject SQL commands into an SQL statement, via web page input.

Injected SQL commands can alter SQL statement and compromise the security of a web application.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: oh? I see. Then I think I'll stop doing it the way like this. Thanks for the information. :)